# How to keep a local WordPress copy in sync with the online repo?

Tags: wordpress, git, github

I would like to have a local copy of the [WordPress repo](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress) from GitHub.

I start with a `clone`:

```
git clone https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress.git
```

Since I do some development with this WordPress I like to exclude ceratin files/folders to get updated. My .gitignore looks like this:

```
.DS_Store
sftp-config.json
wp-content/*
wp-config.php
svn/*
wc-logs/*
```

Sometimes during development I need to modify some core file (basic variable output, bypass caching etc.).

To get back to the initial state I try

```
git remote update
```

but doesn't overwrite the changed files.

```
git rebase master
```

doesn't work cause there are unstaged changes.

```
git pull --all
```

doesn't work either.

How can I update the local repo **including all changes and branches** of the online version?

Comment: I you are trying to reverse the local changes  git checkout -- . will do the trick but I'm not sure if that is what are you asking

Comment: basically I like to keep my local development in sync with the online, including version updates

Comment: first take backup of your files and after that stash your changes and after that take a pull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it finally:

```
#checkout to master (latest beta)
git checkout master

#stash any changes
git stash save "reload"

#get everything from the repo
git pull --all
git pull --tags
git fetch origin

#optional: show the 5 most recent changes
git log --oneline -5

#check out to the latest stable (manual adjusted)
git checkout -q 4.5.3
```

switching to the current beta is easy with `git checkout master`. You can always switch to any version

Answer (score 1):

First stash your changes

```
git stash save "my local changes which I will apply later after getting latest"
```

Then

```
git pull
```